# Where are thunderbird messages saved while offline?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, offline

Yesterday I wrote an email while offline and, since it was not ready I chose the "save" option instead of "send later".

My account is a gmail account and now that I'm connected, I can't find the message I had written.

Can anybody help me find this message?

It is not in the drafts folder, nor in outbox, inbox or sent items. Local folders is empty.

Comment: It may be in 'drafts' on the Gmail account (online).  Can you check using the web interface to Gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the output of `grep draft_folder ~/.thunderbird/*/prefs.js`

I advice to use the thunderbird GUI for accessing this data ;-) 
If the draft folder is not shown, check that this folder is *subscribed*.

Comment: That was probably it. It was not subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be located in your Drafts folder - if it is not there then it probably was not saved.

Go > Folder > Local Folders > Drafts

Comment: Probably when you set Thunderbird to save drafts in am imap folder, if you're offline saving doesn't work. This could be considered a bug.